# Table cell hides equations at the bottom of the page

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2007

I have some tables in my MS word docs. Many times when the table spans multiple pages and when there is an equation in the cell on the boundary on two pages, the table's bottom boundary will not simply move down completely to the bottom of the first page to display all equations that are there in the cell on the first page. This can be seen in the screenshot below:

[image]

Above there is an equation in the cell in the first page. The cell continues on 2nd page also. As you can see, the bottom boundary of the table on first page is not moved completely to the bottom of the first page thus hiding the equations. However, I can click inside hidden equations and also hover on them. The equation body/frame/container responds to these mouse events, but the equation itself is not shown, only the equations body/frame/container is shown/highlighted. I usually do Enter, that is put new lines, so that the whole equation is moved to new page but inside same cell.

Why word is behaving in such a weird way!!!???

Answer (score 0):

Select the row with the equation that is pushed off of the page and then from the Table Layout tab select Properties > Row and tick the box to allow row to break across pages.

Comment: ok that seems to fix if the row move fully onto the next page, if it cannot contain one of its cell content completely onto to the earlier page. That is not my problem right? My row is spanning across page boundaries. But it is hiding equations on first page.